# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store <22/06/2012 12:00:00 AM> in Purchase Date Column.Expected type is DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am receiving this exception on XP running machine but on windows 7, there is no issue. I am trying to format date time as follows,

```
dr.BeginEdit();                                     
dr["Pdate"] = ((DateTime)dr[dc]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dr.EndEdit();
dr.AcceptChanges();
```

It is working fine for '2012-03-04 00:00:00.000' but issue is for '2011-06-22 00:00:00.000'
Any idea?

Comment: The code you have posted shows you are doing 4 completely unnecessary conversions to assign `dr["PDate"]` to itself. You convert from `Date` &rarr; `String` &rarr; `Date` &rarr; `String` and then back to `Date` again! Please can you post your real code?

Comment: @GregB It's almost certainly a DataRow. Given the error message, the type of `dr["PDate"]` is a DateTime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the following in web.config file and it solved the problem.

```
<globalization culture="en-GB"/>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an explicit culture when you Convert.ToDateTime. It's probable that the default culture is different on affected machines,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130987.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably caused by mistaking month with day.

If you know the date format, you could try to use `DateTime.ParseExact`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

For example:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["Pdate"].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Also throwing  Message : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code this helps me and I am sure it will help you too:

```
dr.BeginEdit();                                     
dr["Pdate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[dc]).ToString("your format"); 
dr.EndEdit();
dr.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: will throw the same exception

Comment: I have not received such exceptions on my system.

Comment: I am using .net 3.5, VS 2008. seems that dr["Pdate"] doesnt accept "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", for ex. 22/06/2012

Comment: Is this code still throwing exception.."well it works fine in 3.5 at my end too..

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store a string in a DateTime column. Please try this code:

```
dr.BeginEdit();                                     
dr["Pdate"] = (DateTime)dr[dc]; // No need to convert this to a string :)
dr.EndEdit();
dr.AcceptChanges();
```